# deterministic quickselect for ith order statistic python(medians of median approach)

Tags: python, algorithm, error-handling, quicksort, implementation

`dselect` find the ith order statistic in a given list of unsorted ints (without duplicates) in O(n) time, piggybacking on the principle of quicksort. ith order statistic is defined as the ith smallest element in the sorted version on the given list. So 1st order statistic would be the smallest element and nth order statistic would be the largest element and so on...

On running, I get `IndexError: list index out of range` on `return arr[l]` at the end of the `dselect` function. I think the error arises due to me hard-coding `l` as `0` in the recursive call on the list `medians` on the `dselect` function. (line 4)

What should I do to avoid this error? How should I put the value of `l` in that recursive call? Is that even the source of this error? If this is a stupid question feel free to point that out and I'll delete this question. I just had to ask this because I've been stuck on this for quite a while now. Thanks.

```
def dselect(arr, l, r, i):
    if l < r:
        #finding pivot deterministically
        medians = createMedianList(arr, l, r)
        pivot = dselect(medians, 0, len(medians) - 1, len(medians) // 2) #line4

        pivot = partition(arr, l, r, pivot)
        if pivot + 1 == i:
            return arr[pivot]
        elif pivot + 1 > i:
            return dselect(arr, l, pivot - 1, i)
        else:
            return dselect(arr, pivot + 1, r, i)

    return arr[l]

def partition(arr, l, r, pivot):
    pivotIndex, i = arr.index(pivot), l
    arr[l], arr[pivotIndex] = arr[pivotIndex], arr[l]

    for j in range(l + 1, r + 1):
        if arr[j] < arr[l]:
            i += 1
            arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
    arr[l], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[l]

    return i

def createMedianList(arr, l, r):
    medians = []
    for i in range(l, (r + 1) - 5 + 1):
        temp = sorted(arr[i:i + min(5, (r - l + 1) - i)])
        medians.append(temp[len(temp) // 2])

    return medians

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = [5, 2, 4, 3, 1, -1]
    #arr = list(map(int, open('select.txt').read().splitlines()))
    print(dselect(arr, 0, len(arr) - 1, int(input('Which order 
    statistic to find? '))))
```

Comment: what is createMedianList supposed to do?

Comment: @supinf it creates a list of n/5 medians where n is input length. It does so by dividing given input list in groups of 5, trivially sorting them and returning their respective medians in a list. Please wiki median of medians approach for more. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `createMedianList` sometimes returns an empty list:
This happens if `l >= r-3` which will eventually happen.
I suggest that you add something to `createMedianList` to make sure that it doesnt return an empty list.
E.g.: `if medians==[]:medians=[arr[0]]` or something similar (depending on what properties do you want to have for the medians).

Comment: YES! Thank you so much! I was so fixated on the recursive call on line 4 I never even thought of this. I created if-conditions for when `l < r - 3` and for when it's not. I still get the wrong answer but at least I don't get any errors anymore.